# Calculating volume of a vessel using idea gas law

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

> To an evacuated vessel with movable piston under external pressure of $\pu{1 atm},$ $\ce{0.1 mol}$ of $\ce{He}$ and $\pu{1 mol}$ of unknown compound (vapour pressure $\pu{0.68 atm}$ at $\pu{273 K})$ are introduced. Considering ideal gas behavior, calculate the total volume of 2 gases at $\pu{273 K}.$

Why can't I add the amounts of substance for helium and the unknown compound and directly use $PV=nRT?$ Why is the vapour pressure given?

Comment: **HINT** - Some of the unknown compound is in the liquid state.

Comment: @MaxW Ok. Now I got it. Since external pressure is greater than saturated vapour pressure, the unkown liquid will be in vapour form and by obtaining Partial pressure of He (1-0.68), I can proceed with ideal gas equation.

Comment: Yes, the volume will be the volume for which 0.1 mole of He has a partial pressure of 0.32 atm at 273K. The other 0.68 atm will be the unknown compound.